# using getline() while separating comma didn't work

Tags: c++, csv, getline

I have read a CSV file that has line ending character as '\r', the reading operation done successfully, but the problem started when i pass the read line in to the `while(getline(ss,arr2,','))` for separating comma..it does work properly for the first line but all the next iterations are empty(i.e)it has been failing to separate the comma in the string.

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter the file path :";
    string filename;
    cin>>filename;
    ifstream file;
    vector<string>arr;
    string line,var;
    stringstream content;
    file.open(filename.c_str(),ios::in );
    line.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    file.close();
    string arr2;
    stringstream ss;
    content<<line;
    //sqlite3 *db;int rc;sqlite3_stmt * stmt;
    int i=0;
    while (getline(content,var,'\r'))
    {
        ss.str(var);//for each read the ss contains single line which i could print it out.
        cout<<ss.str()<<endl;
        while(getline(ss,arr2,','))//here the first line is neatly separated and pushed into vector but it fail to separate second and further lines i was really puzzled about this behaviour.
        {
            arr.push_back(arr2);
        }
        ss.str("");
        var="";
        arr2="";
        for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
        {
            cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
        }
        arr.clear();
    }
    getch();
}
```

what went wrong in the above...I see nothing right now:(

Comment: Use a local `stringstream ss;` inside the while loop or `ss.clear()`  to reset the stream state

Comment: @DieterLücking,just for curiosity doesn't the ss.str("")  clear the stream?

Comment: @DieterLücking,That worked:)

Comment: @RichardGeorge `ss.str("")` clears the content of the stream, not its state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stringstream::str` method does not reset / clear the internal state of the stream. After the first line, the internal state of `ss` is `EOF` (`ss.eof()` returns `true`).

Either use a local variable inside the `while` loop:

```
while (getline(content,var,'\r'))
{
    stringstream ss(var);
```

Or clear the stream before `ss.str`:

```
ss.clear();
ss.str(var);
```